# How to make the time out of one connection of the server while not affecting following accesses?

Tags: scheme, racket

I have written an web application in racket, the server is running fine after I deployed it. The problem is that, after my timeout, the first time it will serve the `timeout.html` page, but after that, if I access the same web page again, server throws the following exception:

```
Exception

The application raised an exception with the message:

procedure application: expected procedure, given: #f; arguments were: #<request>

Stack trace:

<unknown procedure> at:
  line 58, column 2, in file /Applications/Racket v5.2.1/collects/web-server/dispatchers/dispatch-servlets.rkt
select-handler/no-breaks at:
  line 166, column 2, in file /Applications/Racket v5.2.1/collects/racket/private/more-scheme.rkt
connection-loop at:
  line 74, column 2, in file /Applications/Racket v5.2.1/collects/web-server/private/dispatch-server-unit.rkt
```

Any idea what's the problem? is it because of the timeout manager? which I also attached here how I defined the manager:

```
#:manager (create-timeout-manager 
                          (lambda (req) 
                            (response/full
     200 #"Okay"
     (current-seconds) TEXT/HTML-MIME-TYPE
     empty
     (list (string->bytes/utf-8 (include-template "templates/timeout.html")))))
                             3600 3600)
```

If I didn't specify timeout manager right, then how to make the time out of one connection of the server while not affecting following accesses?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to need more information about the rest of your program, because everything about your timeout manager is correct and I'm able to get the proper behavior with it on my test machine.

Jay, Racket Web Server maintainer